# "eventual period" of group elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for composite $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To introduce things, consider the element $2$ in the integers mod $100$ under multiplication. The powers (starting at the first power) are $2,4,8,16,32,64,28,56,\cdots,76,52,$ after which the sequence repeats but starting at $4,$ a bit like the decimal of a rational whose period does not start immediately. The repeating part of the sequence has length $20.$ I am wondering some things about this behavior for general composite $n$ and the base of the powers $a$ which is *not* coprime to $n.$

Some questions I have: Is there a way to predict the length of the period? [meaning the least positive $p$ so that there is some $n_0$ for which $a^{n+p}=a^n$ for each $n \ge n_0.$]

Another question: Are there any examples of such composite $n$ and $a$ not coprime to $n$ for which the repeating part begins immediately? [i.e. $n_0=1$ in the above description]

I would also appreciate any information about anything known about this topic. Thank you.

Comment: The way to answer all these questions is to look at the period modulo the prime-power divisors of the modulus ($4$ and $25$ in this case), and then use the fact that the overall period is the least common multiple of all these sub-periods.

Comment: @GregMartin So for 2 mod 100 how does one deal with the period of 2 mod 4? is that period 1 since all powers after the second of 2 are 0 mod 4? And since 2 is a primitive root mod 25 these would explain why the period of 2 mod 100 is 20? Thanks for your comment, just wanted to be sure if I understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ has prime factorization $\prod_j{p_j^{k_j}}$, then it is a consequence of the Chinese Remainder theorem, that $$o_n(a)=\max_j{o_{p_j^{k_j}}(a)}$$ where $o_n$ is the length of the period mod $n$.  Moreover, if $a=p_j^{\alpha}$, then $$o_{p_j^{k_j}}(a)=\begin{cases}
(p_j-1)p_j^{k_j-1} & p_j\nmid a \\
\left\lfloor\frac{k_j}{\alpha}\right\rfloor & {p_j^{\alpha}\mid a}\wedge {p_j^{\alpha+1}\nmid a}
\end{cases}$$  This follows from considering the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo $p_j^{k_j}$.

In your example, $100=2^25^2$.  $2$ is divisible by $2$, so $o_{2^2}(2)=2$.  But $2$ is coprime to $5$, so $o_{5^2}(2)=4\cdot5^1=20$, as you computed.

> Are there any examples of such composite $n$ and $a$ not coprime to $n$ for which the repeating part begins immediately?

Yes, $0$ is an example.  Less trivially, $2\pmod{6}$; in general, if there are no primes that divide $a$ whose square divide $n$, then the power sequence of $a\pmod{n}$ starts repeating immediately.

Comment: I already accepted, but I'm left doubting what you said as a source of cases where the repeat block starts immediately. Namely, 2 is a prime dividing 100, yet among the powers of 2 [taken mod 100] the 2 itself never reappears, and so in that case the period fails to start right away.

Comment: @coffeemath The answer is incorrect, so why did you accept it?

Comment: @BillDubuque I see. I will unaccept.

Comment: Jacob: I unaccepted at Bill's suggestion. If you deal with the second question I'll reconsider.

Comment: @coffeemath: Yes, my first response was wrong.  I've replaced it with a correct one now.

Comment: OK that is a good answer for my second question, will "re-accept". It's more general than my adjustment with $a=p,\ n=p^k-p$ for prime $p$ and $k$ large enough to make $n>a.$